# the physical problem behind the stochastic flows?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-pde

I don't know whether it is a right platform to ask the question like this ,my question is pretty much basic I want to know about what was the most basic problem from which the subject of stochastic flows started or what is the problem in physics which uses the stochastic flows?,I looked at the book by [stochastic flows](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805213/50501/sample/9780521350501ws.pdf)

but it is a mathematician direct approach but I am searcing for a text with a touch from physics / Can anybody help me?